# How to align SLF4J Log output?

Tags: java, logging, logback, slf4j

For testing purposes, default log outputs too long lines which become hard to read.

Currently, I'd just like to have an abbreviated class and the output given to `log.info` and for it to be aligned on the `---` symbols.

I just this format currently:

```
logging.pattern.console=%c{1}           --- %m%n
```

I guess `%n` means "new line", `%c` means "class", `{1}` abbreviates the fully qualified name (which is good). The output I'm getting is:

```
d.e.e.Eva04p2Beanlifecycle           --- No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
d.e.e.s.SmallService           --- doBeforeInitializing before upadating ... what's my personal name? frieda
d.e.e.s.SmallService           --- doBeforeInitializing ... what's my personal name? marga
d.e.e.Eva04p2Beanlifecycle           --- Started Eva04p2Beanlifecycle in 0.628 seconds (JVM running for 0.824)
d.e.e.s.SmallService           --- doSomething ... what's my personal name? marga
d.e.e.s.SmallService           --- doBeforeDestroying ... what's my personal name? elisa
```

using these kinds of instructions:

```
@PostConstruct
public void doBeforeInitializing() {
    log.info("doBeforeInitializing before upadating ... what's my personal name? " + myPersonalName);
    myPersonalName = "marga";
    log.info("doBeforeInitializing ... what's my personal name? " + myPersonalName);
}

public void doSomething() {
    log.info("doSomething ... what's my personal name? " + myPersonalName);
}

@PreDestroy
public void doBeforeDestroying() {
    myPersonalName = "elisa";
    log.info("doBeforeDestroying ... what's my personal name? " + myPersonalName);
}
```

What do I need to change, such that all `---` are printed aligned above each other?

Comment: slf4j doesn't control the output logging format, that's determined by whatever logging implementation you're using? Is this a Spring Boot application?

Comment: @E-Riz Correct, it's a Spring Boot application.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments above, slf4j doesn't control the format of the log output - that's done by the logging implementation you are using ([slf4j is just a facade/abstraction, not an implementation](https://www.slf4j.org/#:%7E:text=The%20Simple%20Logging%20Facade%20for%20Java%20(SLF4J)%20serves%20as%20a%20simple%20facade%20or%20abstraction%20for%20various%20logging%20frameworks%20(e.g.%20java.util.logging%2C%20logback%2C%20log4j)%20allowing%20the%20end%20user%20to%20plug%20in%20the%20desired%20logging%20framework%20at%20deployment%20time.)). In Spring Boot applications, the default logging implementation is logback, and logback's pattern formatter supports left and right padding "columns" as well as setting min and max widths. Together, those formatting options can get what you're asking for.

Rather than give you and exact format, I urge you to [read the documentation](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#formatModifiers) and determine which format you want. There are a lot of possible combinations to consider, and that page even has examples to help determine which you want.

Answer (score 0):

The logback docs are looooong. Here's the part you're looking for.

Logback can be configured to print your class name in a fixed length field, padding the rest with spaces by adding a modifier after the `%`.

The length of your longest class name is 26. We can add that value to the format, but that will right-justify it which doesn't look right to me for this data.

I would prefer this data to be left justified, so I have added a `-` as well.

The example from your post:

```
logging.pattern.console=%c{1}           --- %m%n
```

modified to print the class name in a fixed length field:

```
logging.pattern.console=%-26c{1}           --- %m%n
```

And now the data after your class names will be evenly aligned because your class names all take up the same amount of space:

```
d.e.e.Eva04p2Beanlifecycle           --- No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
d.e.e.s.SmallService                 --- doBeforeInitializing before upadating ... what's my personal name? frieda
```

Here's a link to
[the specific part of the logback documentation on fixed length fields](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#:%7E:text=20%20characters%20long.-,%25%2D20logger,-true)